# SwiftUI: When I unlock apps it takes me back to the list

Tags: core-data, swiftui

I have some problem with my application. When I lock it while I am in the content view and then unlock it, it takes me back to the list. I would like the view I was in before locking to still be visible after unlocking. I have tried to get this effect somehow but not successfully. Please, give me a hint.

What is more, if I click the heart and the item is marked as favorite, it also moves me back to the list. Here I would also like to remain in the view after selecting the heart. How can I eliminate this?

Comment: Use SceneStorage instead of State for the variables where you want to maintain the users state

Comment: Cast it to plain Song it is hard to help [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). But make sure you are only using it so save the selection value. ObservableObjects/CoreData objects should be wrapped in an ObservedObject for editing and seeing changes.

Comment: How exactly do I use SceneStorage?

Comment: It works like AppStorage. Use the NavigationLink with selection in it and use SceneStorage to save the selection. I’ll try to type up an answer in a bit

Comment: This needs a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). I am going to recommend that you keep the core data in, but you need to provide your core data model( a screenshot works) and don't leave out code. You have referenced functions `save()` and `alert()` in your code, but you don't show them. Your issues could be a side effect somewhere. Also, how do you handle `ScenePhase`, if at all?

Comment: @Yrb Regarding the "save" and "alert" functions and ScenePhase, I added the code to the body of the main question.

Comment: @loremipsum I've added the missing items in the main question, which should help.

Comment: @oculorum I added an answer below. It works with the standard project. Your code has way more going on than is needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample usage using Apple's sample code since you didn't provide any entity info

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    
    @FetchRequest(
        sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Item.timestamp, ascending: true)],
        animation: .default)
    private var items: FetchedResults<Item>
    //SceneStorage to preserve the selected item by the user
    @SceneStorage("ContentView.selection") var selection: String?
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(items) { item in
                    //Use the NavigationLink that uses selection
                    NavigationLink(tag: item.objectID.description, selection: $selection,
                                   destination: {
                        //to edit/ observe the item pass it to an @ObservedObject
                        EditItemView2(item: item)
                    }, label: {
                        VStack{
                            Text(item.timestamp!, formatter: itemFormatter)
                        }
                        
                    })
                    Button("delete", action: {
                        withAnimation(.easeOut(duration: 2)){
                            try? viewContext.delete(item)
                        }
                    })
                }.onDelete(perform: deleteItems)
            }
            
        }
        .toolbar {
#if os(iOS)
            ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                EditButton()
            }
#endif
            ToolbarItem {
                Button(action: addItem) {
                    Label("Add Item", systemImage: "plus")
                }
            }
        }
        Text("Select an item")
        
    }
    
    private func addItem() {
        withAnimation {
            let newItem = Item(context: viewContext)
            newItem.timestamp = Date()
            do {
                try viewContext.save()
            } catch {
                let nsError = error as NSError
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func deleteItems(offsets: IndexSet) {
        withAnimation(.easeOut(duration: 2)) {
            offsets.map { items[$0] }.forEach(viewContext.delete)
            
            do {
                try viewContext.save()
            } catch {
                let nsError = error as NSError
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
            }
        }
    }
}

private let itemFormatter: DateFormatter = {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateStyle = .short
    formatter.timeStyle = .medium
    return formatter
}()

struct EditItemView2: View{
    //This observes the item and allows changes to the object
    @ObservedObject var item: Item
    var body: some View{
        DatePicker("timestamp", selection: $item.timestamp.bound)
    }
}
```

This page talks all about it

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/view_controllers/restoring_your_app_s_state_with_swiftui

Comment: Thank you very much for the tip, additionally it appeared that the following snippet was complicating the application.`.id(UUID())`

Comment: @oculorum That if thing is a bad habit that is spreading around here is causes unnecessary redrawing when you have some time watch demystify SwiftUI from WWDC 21

Answer (score 1):

If your view is the first to create your `UserSettings` object, I recommend that you use `@StateObject` instead of `@ObservedObject`—and especially if that object is the only owner of the view and is not being observed by any other view.